# Columns Block no longer appears when searching

Tags: columns

I have a strange problem. the core columns block has gone missing. https://wordpress.org/support/article/columns-block/ I can no longer search for it. Has anyone else experienced this? Odd thing is I noticed it gone in my local trellis build a while ago but could not see why. Now, after using on some posts, it is missing from our production build. Certain posts are crashing when editing and I’m wondering if it is related[image]

Comment: Try disabling plugins; recently experienced an issue where upon updating WP itself, two plugins are conflicting with one another with one preventing the other's blocks from loading.